# Speech To Text for 2 button and 2 edit text (android)

Tags: android, speech-to-text

I am new android developer. Please, I would like to create activity with two edittext and for each button with Speech To Text function. I found just code, which I post bellow. But I can not able iplement it for two buttons and two edittext. Thanks for any advice.

```
package info.androidhive.speechtotext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText txtSpeechInput1, txtSpeechInput2;
private Button btnSpeak1, btnSpeak2;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT = 100;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSpeechInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput1);
    txtSpeechInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput2);
    btnSpeak1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak1);
    btnSpeak2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak2);

    // hide the action bar
    getActionBar().hide();

    btnSpeak1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });

    btnSpeak2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput();
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
private void promptSpeechInput() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput1.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    }

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
package info.androidhive.speechtotext;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.RecognizerIntent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private EditText txtSpeechInput1, txtSpeechInput2;
private Button btnSpeak1, btnSpeak2;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT1 = 101;
private final int REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT2 = 102;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSpeechInput1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput1);
    txtSpeechInput2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSpeechInput2);
    btnSpeak1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak1);
    btnSpeak2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak2);

    // hide the action bar
    getActionBar().hide();

    btnSpeak1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput(REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT1);
        }
    });

    btnSpeak2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            promptSpeechInput(REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT2);
        }
    });

}

/**
 * Showing google speech input dialog
 * */
private void promptSpeechInput(int req) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,
            getString(R.string.speech_prompt));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, req);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getString(R.string.speech_not_supported),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Receiving speech input
 * */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT1: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput1.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;
    case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT2: {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

            ArrayList<String> result = data
                    .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            txtSpeechInput2.setText(result.get(0));
        }
        break;

    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
android
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works very well. Just add one bracket (}) behind first "break" in "protected void onActivityResult".